# Can you have WPF references in an XNA project for xbox 360

Tags: windows, xna, xbox360

I'm writing a XNA project in both Windows and Xbox 360 and the Windows side of it has a console I bring up written as a WPF application.  What I was wondering is if I leave this in my library code with the references to WPF, will the dll still work on the 360?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  You're limited to using the .NET Compact Framework on the XBOX 360.  This will not include WPF.

In fact, you're limited to the XBOX 360's implementation of the Compact Framework, which is built off the .NET 2.0 Compact Framework.  This means that any .NET 3.0/3.5 specific classes will not work.  MSDN lists the entire collection of the [supported namespaces, types, and members for the XBOX 360](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203915.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, was afraid of that.  Forgot that it was .NET Compact on 360.

Comment: @Reed I'm think you might be wrong there. You're right that the Xbox 360 implementation doesn't implement all of the namespaces and types in the Compact Framework, but as far as I know it's only System.Windows.Forms, System.Web and some of System.Net that's left out (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb198211.aspx). Features such as LINQ (which is .NET 3.0+ specific no?) will work.

Comment: @Tchami: No.  It's a customized .NET 2.0 CF.  LINQ will not work on the xbox (it will work with XNA on PC).  See the link above - it explicitly lists all of the types and namespaces that work on the 360.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're wrong. In fact, one of the default namespaces being included when you create a Xbox 360 game is System.Linq. In fact, to be 120% sure I just deployed said project template to my Xbox and it runs perfectly. The documentation must be wrong/outdated.

Comment: @Tchami: Looks like the linked documentation is incorrect (even though it's for 3.1).  WPF will NOT work, though - I'm 100% sure of that.  I guess they got LINQ added at XNA 3.0, from what I'm seeing.

Comment: @Reed: Indeed, WPF will not work and I never questioned that ;)